# Authentication using python requests. Getting redirect to login page

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests library to login the site:

http://www.zsrcpod.aviales.ru/login/login_auth2.pl

and then trying to get a file, but authentication fails and i am gettin redirect to login page.

I already had some experience in using requests library for other sites and it works fine with `.seesion`, but this script is not working:

```
login_to_site_URL= r'http://www.zsrcpod.aviales.ru/login/login_auth2.pl'
URL = r"http://www.zsrcpod.aviales.ru/modistlm-cgi/seances.pl?db=modistlm"

payload = {r'login': r'XXXXXX',
           r'second': r'XXXXXX'}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_to_site_URL, payload)

    load = s.get(URL, stream=True) 

    # download
    with open('G:\!Download\!TEST.html', "wb") as save_command:
        for chunk in load.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                save_command.write(chunk)
                save_command.flush()
```

I need a help with adopting it.

Comment: Looking at the form source, the login field is called `first`, not `login`.

Comment: When iterating over `iter_content()` there is no need to test if `chunk` is empty, really.

Comment: Have you taken into account that the page may have additional hidden form elements that need to be submitted too? There is JS code as well, that sets the `mode` hidden field to `in` when submitting.

Comment: 'first' filed is not working too. Can I somehow find  this hidden fields?

Comment: You look at the page source.

Comment: Thx a lot this one is working fine: `payload = {r'first': r'xxxxxxxxx',
           r'second': r'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
           r'mode': r'in',
           r'lang': r'rus',
           r'from': r'/',
           r'history': r'1',
           r'req_meth': r'0',
           r'code': r'0',
           r'project': r'aviales',
           r'remembercid': r'1'
           }`